# File Fail To Upload

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Started learning nodejs recently, and am currently trying to perform a task that involves file upload.. With the aid of multer documentation and Youtube video, was able to set up the module and middleware and file path etc. but for some reasons, the file don't upload. i can see the file object in my console, but my browser keeps loading.

Would love if someone can help point my errors to allow the file upload to specifies folder, and also give me a tip on how to trap errors not rendered on the error file Thank you. Below are my codes:

**register.hbs**

```
{{>header}}
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h2>{{this.title}}</h2>
 <div class="mb-3">
      {{#each data}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
   <div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd">
  </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputFile" class="form-label">Select Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3 form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

router file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const {check,validationResult}= require('express-validator');
const multer=require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    }
  })
  
  var upload = multer({ 
      storage: storage,
    limits:{
        fieldSize:1024*1024*100
    } })

router.post('/register',upload.single('image'), [
    check('fname')
        .isLength({ min: 8 })
        .withMessage('First name must be minimum of 8 characters')
        .isAlpha()
        .withMessage('first name must contain only alphabeth'),
    check('lname').isLength({min:8}),
    check('email').isEmail()
  ], (req, res,next)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req)
   
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        //const data=errors.array();
        console.log(errors)
        res.render('users/register',{title:"Create Account", data:errors.array()});
      //return res.status(422).json({errors: errors.array()})
    }
    console.log(req.file)
  const fname  = req.body.fname
  const lname  = req.body.lname
  const email = req.body.email
  
    console.log(req.errors)
   // res.render('users/register');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about your case, in my case I using multer like this:

I seperate multer to a file multerUploaderMiddleware.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const util = require("util");

 //Change this to diskStorage like your code above
 //I use memory storage
  const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage()

function chapterIsExisted(req) {
    // My custom error handling function
    return (
        Chapter
            .findOne({ comicSlug: req.params.slug, chapter: `chapter-${req.body.chapter}` })
            .then(chapterExisted => {
                if (chapterExisted == null) { return false }
                return true
            }))
};

// This filter function for error handling
const filter = async (req, file, cb) => {
   //as I remember if you want the file to success
   // then return cb(null, true)
   // else return cb(null, false)
   
    if (req.check == 'nocheck') {
        return cb(null, true)
    } else {
        
        var check = await chapterIsExisted(req)
        if (check == false) {
            cb(null, true)
        } else {
            let errorMess = `chapter ${req.body.chapter} existed`
            return cb(errorMess, false);
        }
    }
    
};

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerStorage,
    fileFilter: filter
}).single("image", 200);

// Turn this middleware function into promise
let multipleUploadMiddleware = util.promisify(upload);

module.exports = multipleUploadMiddleware;
```

And In my route controller:

```
// get the exported function
const MulterUploadMiddleware =          
require("../middlewares/MulterUploadMiddleWare");

class S3UploadController {

    // [POST] / stored /comics /:slug /S3-multiple-upload
    
    multipleUpload = async (req, res, next) => {
        // The function you exported from middleware above
        MulterUploadMiddleware(req, res)
        .then(async () => { 
            //when the upload is done you get some data back here
            Console.log(req.file)         
            // do stuff

        })
        .then(() => res.redirect('back'))
        .catch(err => next(err))
      })
     }
```

Comment: If no action is set, it submits to the current url.